# "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in c

Tags: c, struct

Ok, I've seen this question on google a million times, but still no success for me.
I am trying to create a linked list. Here's the struct defined in `List.c`:

```
typedef struct List
{
    unsigned int size;
    ObjectP head;
} List;
```

Now as you'll notice both the struct and the typedef are named LIST, which is fine as far as I know. But the important thing is that the struct is NOT anonymous.

Now in `List.h` (which of course is included in `List.c`)I've defined another typedef:

```
typedef struct List* ListP;
```

Which as far as I understand it defines ListP to be a pointer to a struct called List, just like I really named it.

And here's where I get the errors:

```
void freeList(ListP list)
{
    ObjectP obj1;
    ObjectP obj2;
    if (list != NULL)
    {
        obj1 = list->head;
        while (obj1->next != NULL)   <---- HERE
        {
            obj2 = obj1;
            obj1 = obj1->next;   <---- HERE
        freeObject(obj2);
        }
    free(list);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `obj1 = list->head;` is ok, but everywhere else I try to gain access to struct members I have this error. 
As I said I've tried looking for it, but other ppl had mistakes I can't find in my code. Thanks!

EDIT: `List.c` also includes `Object.h` so this is not the problem. The definition of object as is follow:

in `Object.h` I have `typedef struct Object* ObjectP`;
and in `Object.c` I have

```
typedef struct Object
{
    void* key;
    ObjectP next;
} Object;
```

Still don't know what the problem is!

Comment: where is `next` defined?

Comment: Care to include in the code what `ObjectP` is?

Comment: How do you define ObjectP? Is it properly defined before you define the List struct using it?

Comment: And what is `ObjectP`?  I assume you are using it as a node within your list, but you didn't provide any definition of it.  You're getting errors because of how you are using an `ObjectP`, not because of anything related to your `ListP` type.

Comment: Your problem begins and ends with the part that goes "and in Object.c I have [definition of `Object`]".  If it's in your `Object.c` file then the code you have in `List.c` does not know about any of the fields that make up an `Object`.  Hence the error when you try to access one.  You need to define your `Object` structure inside of `Object.h` instead (or remove the references to things inside of this structure from `List.c`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you define the struct for `ObjectP` in a different C file (probably Object.c). When the compiler is compiling List.c, it doesn't know anything defined in other c files, it only knows what's been defined in h files that have been included in the current c file.

Structs that are shared by different c files have to be defined in a header file that can be included in all of them. So if you just move the definition for `struct Object` to Object.h, you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectP` is defined as a pointer to `Object` and `Object` has a member of type `ObjectP`. This is a circular dependency.

Try:

```
typedef struct object_st {
    void* key;
    struct object_st *next;
} Object;

typedef ObjectP *Object;
```

Oh, and cast for assignment:

```
obj1 = (ObjectP) obj1->next;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the order in your typedef is switched around.

Comment: what do you mean? it compiles here.

Comment: A cast can't solve an "incomplete type" problem. @bmearns got the real problem.